# Embedding GWT application in ChromiumEmbedded

Tags: gwt, chromium, chromium-embedded

I have read through the chromiumembedded usage and looked at the cefclient application. Now i would like to provide my gwt application as an standalone application to my customers. Is it possible to package the gwt client code using chromiummebedded.

I am not sure how to make the RPC/RC calls to the server if its packaged in CEF.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include an embedded webserver in your application, and serve the generated GWT application files from this.

Since the url for your server will be different, you could disable the same origin policy in ChromiumEmbedded to use normal RPC calls, but it might be better to use cross domain calls as describe in [Googles tutorial](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/Xsite.html)